# How can I reduce duplication in my JavaScript if syntax?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to reduce duplication in my JavaScript syntax.

No matter how much I think about it, it doesn't come to mind.

It doesn't matter if it is for loop or any syntax!

i add some of case and result

if if it is correct answer would be result

```
    //   case 1

  //  const max = [1, 31, 0, 0]

  //  const min = [1, 31];
  
  //  result = [3, 5]

  //   case 2

  // const max = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

  // const min = [0, 0]

  //  result = [1, 6]

  //   case 3

  // const max = [45, 4, 35, 20, 3, 9]

  // const min = [45, 4, 35, 20, 3, 9]
  
  //  result = [1, 1]

    if (max.length === 6) {
      answer[0] = 1;
    } else if (max.length === 5) {
      answer[0] = 2;
    } else if (max.length === 4) {
      answer[0] = 3;
    } else if (max.length === 3) {
      answer[0] = 4;
    } else if (max.length === 2) {
      answer[0] = 5;
    } else {
      answer[0] = 6;
    }

    if (min.length === 6) {
      answer[1] = 1;
    } else if (min.length === 5) {
      answer[1] = 2;
    } else if (min.length === 4) {
      answer[1] = 3;
    } else if (min.length === 3) {
      answer[1] = 4;
    } else if (min.length === 2) {
      answer[1] = 5;
    } else {
      answer[1] = 6;
    }
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for simple arithmetic: `answer = [7-max.length, 7-min.length];`

Comment: I believe @Bergi has provided the correct answer. But whenever you have a similar situation again where such a solution is not possible at least use a [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) or map the values using a JS Object.

Comment: Try this: `answer[0] = max.length <= 6 ? 7 - max.length : 6;` and `answer[1] = min.length <= 6 ? 7 - min.length : 6;`.

Comment: @jsN00b i tired but it some thing wrong

Comment: I posted an answer. Will add more notes to it.

Comment: What is all that code that you added to the top?  It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: OP is trying to provide examples of what the two array's `max` and `min` may look like. Sort-of like test cases, I think. And the `result` is what is expected. And, case 2 - does seem incorrect to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const getAnswers = x => (x < 1 || x > 6) ? 6 : 7 - x;

//   case 1
let max = [1, 31, 0, 0]
let min = [1, 31];
//  result = [3, 5]
let answer = [getAnswers(max.length), getAnswers(min.length)];
console.log('max.length: ', max.length, ' min.length: ', min.length, ' answer array: ', answer);

//   case 2
max = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
min = [0]
//  result = [1, 6]
answer = [getAnswers(max.length), getAnswers(min.length)];
console.log('max.length: ', max.length, ' min.length: ', min.length, ' answer array: ', answer);

//   case 3
max = [45, 4, 35, 20, 3, 9]
min = [45, 4, 35, 20, 3, 9]
//  result = [1, 1]
answer = [getAnswers(max.length), getAnswers(min.length)];
console.log('max.length: ', max.length, ' min.length: ', min.length, ' answer array: ', answer);
```

Comment: The question says `"Case 2"` has `min` as `[0, 0]` - which has length 2. If length is 2, then the `answer` will be `5`. But, the expected result is `6`. So, in the above snippet, `"Case 2"` has `min` as `[0]` which is of length `1` and this gets the expected result: `[1, 6]`.

Comment: thank you man i understood!!!!!1 thank you for help!

Answer (score 3):

is max and min length between 1 and 6? because judging your code, it looks like it.

```
answer[0] = 7 - max.length
```

sure looks a bit neater, at the least you could eliminate many if blocks and leave the else block in case max.length is not an integer between 1 and 6

```
//pseudocode
if( max.length between 1 and 6 inclusive) {
    answer[0] = 7- max.length
} else { 
    answer[0] = some default value, 6? 
}
```

the 7 looks like a magic number, but with more context, you can name it something better

Answer (score 1):

By reducing duplication, do you mean you want to decrease the length of your code or increase readability?

If you want to increase readability, some people prefer `select/case` than `if/elseif`:

```
switch(max.length) {
  case 6:
    answer[0] = 1;
    break;
  case 5:
    answer[0] = 2;
    break;
  case 4:
    answer[0] = 3;
    break;
  case 3:
    answer[0] = 4;
    break;
  case 2:
    answer[0] = 5;
    break;
  default:
    answer[0] = 6;
}
```

If you want to reduce length, you can just do something like @Bergi said in comment:

```
answer = [7-max.length, 7-min.length];
```

But if `max` and `min` variable is from user input or from external source, unexpected thing may occurs:

```js
max = {length: -5};
min = {length: -99};
answer = [7-max.length, 7-min.length];
console.log(answer)
// outputs [12,106]
```

The code may outputs a number outside 1-6 integer range.

So you should also add some Math.max and Math.min if you want your code to behave exactly like your if-elseif statement:

```js
max = {length: -5};
min = {length: -99};
answer = [
  Math.max(Math.min(7-max.length,1),6),
  Math.max(Math.min(7-min.length,1),6)
 ];
console.log(answer)
// outputs [6,6]
```

Of course if you take input from external source you should sanitize/validate it first, but if it's an overkill, you can also use the above Math.min and Math.max function

Comment: i use your switch code it works! but second one or third one it doesn't work... what did i wrong?.... and i added some of cases in my question. what can i add in length?

Comment: maybe you haven't deleted `max = {length: -5};` and `min = {length: -99};`? those are just example of wrongly (or maybe maliciously) inputted variable

Answer (score 0):

you need to write just these two lines instead :)

```
answer[0] = 7 - max.length
answer[1] = 7 - min.length
```

Comment: in if loop? or just that code?

Comment: @jackvolten no need to loop ,I recognized it from the pattern of your values

Comment: It can also be destructured like `answer = [7 - max.length, 7 - min.length]`

Comment: It can also be destructured like answer = [7 - max.length, 7 - min.length]